# Rails 4 Nested Form with Multiple Tag Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a rails 4 application with a simple has_many and belong_to relationship between cash_receipt and cash_receipt_lines. The cash_receipt_lines are entered as a nested form. My problem comes from the proper way to submit the nested fields.  The user will enter the basic cash_receipt data choosing a client and entering check number and amount.  This will bring up a list of open invoices with a check_box_tag and an amount line as text_field_tag.

cash_receipt_form

```
<%= simple_form_for @cash_receipt, wrapper: :bootstrap, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="span3"> 
    <%= f.input :account_id, label: false, :collection => GlAccount.all, :value_method => :id, :label_method => 
          :fullaccount, :required => false, input_html: { id: "account-lookup", class: "input-xlarge" }  %>  
</div>
<div class="span5">      
<%= f.input :client_id, label: false, collection: Client.all, value_method: :id, label_method: :name,
           input_html: { id: "client-lookup", class: "input-xlarge" } %>           
</div>
<div class="span2">
<%= f.input :no_ar, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false, label: "Ledger Account?" %>   
</div>
  </div>

   <div class="well">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4"> 
  <%= f.input :payment_type, collection: ['Check', 'Cash'], input_html: { :class => "span2" } %>
<%= f.input :check_number, :as => :string, label: "Check #", input_html: { :class => "span2" } %>
 </div>
<div class="span5"> 
 <%= f.input :payment_date, :as => :string, :label => "Payment Date", required: false, :input_html => { :class => "datepicker span2", value: Time.now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') } %>
<%= f.input :amount, label: "Payment Amount", required: false, :as => :currency, input_html: { :class => "span2", 
  id: "client-amount" } %>
</div>
</div>
</div>  

<div class="well">
<div class="row">     
 <div class="span1">
  <h6>Open Items</h6>
    <p></p>
 </div>
</div>

    <div id="openitems">

    <%= render :partial => "payment_lines", :locals => { :aropen => @aropen } unless @aropen.nil? || @aropen.empty? %>
  </div>
</div>          

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save Cash Receipt", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= f.button :cancel, to: cash_receipts_path %>
   </div><!-- actions -->


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#client-lookup').select2({
       placeholder: "Choose a Client",
  allowClear: true
});
$('select#account-lookup').select2({
  placeholder: "Deposit To Account",
  allowClear: true
});
$('select#client-lookup').bind('change', function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<%= update_aropen_cash_receipts_path %>",
    data: {
      client_id : $('select#client-lookup').val()
    },
    dataType: "script"
  });
});  
});
</script>
 <%end%>
```

And cash_receipt_lines partial

```
<table class ="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Selected</th>
     <th>Invoice #</th>
     <th>Balance</th>
     <th>Invoice Amount</th>
     <th>Client</th>
     <th>Invoice Date</th>
     <th>Amount to Apply</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% aropen.each do |ar| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "invoice_header_id[]", ar.id %></td>
      <td><%= ar.id%></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(ar.balance) %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(ar.total_amount) %></td>
      <td><%= ar.name %></td>
      <td><%= ar.invoice_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "cash_receipt[cash_receipt_lines][][applied]" %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So the partial is a simple table with a list of open invoices and they check several and enter the amounts.  On submit I need to be able to create each child record along with the parent.

Models:

```
class CashReceipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cash_receipt_lines, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :invoice_header
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cash_receipt_lines, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end 

class CashReceiptLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cash_receipt

end
```

I started by using cocoon, but that just didn't fit with the invoice list.  Params are still set in the controller though:

```
 def cash_receipt_params
  params.require(:cash_receipt).permit(:payment_date, :payment_type, :account_id, :client_id, :check_aba, :check_number,
                                     :amount, :ar_account_id, :no_ar,:posted, :user_id, 
                                   cash_receipt_lines_attributes: [ :id, :cash_receipt_id, :applied_amount, :invoice_header_id, 
                                   :updated_at, :created_at, :unappliedar, :_destroy])
end
```

How can I properly set params for the create method and save the parent and children while using multiple tag fields per child record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  By changing the array in the cash_receipt_lines partial:

Change:

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "invoice_header_id[]", ar.id %></td>

<td><%= text_field_tag "cash_receipt[cash_receipt_lines][][applied]" %></td>
```

To:

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "cash_receipt[cash_receipt_lines_attributes][#{ar.id}][invoice_header_id]", ar.id %></td>

<td><%= text_field_tag "cash_receipt[cash_receipt_lines_attributes][#{ar.id}][applied_amount]","" %></td>
```

Fixes the issue. No other changes and it creates the proper params and posts correctly! The key is adding an index number to the array.  Just thought I would answer inn case others are pulling their hair out like I was!